# Load a scaled version of a system icon

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

We already have code like this for loading a scaled version of an icon in our project resources, which is used to set the image on a standard `CButton`.

```
HANDLE h = ::LoadImage(::AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IconId),
    IMAGE_ICON,
    width,
    height,
    LR_SHARED);

    pButton->SetIcon((HICON)h);
```

I'd like to do the same with standard icons, as loaded from [SHGetStockIconInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Is this feasible and if so how?

Comment: You'll need to scale the icons yourself

Comment: [SHDefExtractIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762149.aspx).